# Regex to find all substrings and longest substring

Tags: c#, java, regex

I would usually do something like this using a string libray. But  I wonder if it can be done using a regex.

I want to do the following: Given a **search string**:

> Seattle is awesome

I want to find all substrings of it in a given sentence. So applying a regex to the following **sentence**

> Seattle Seattle is awesome is awesome awesome is Seattle

Should give me

> Seattle, Seattle is awesome, is awesome, awesome, is, Seattle

**One constraint that might be helpful is that the sentence will always have only the words present in the search string and whitespaces in between.**

**Note** If there's a match, it should be the longest possible string. So like in the above example the matches shouldn't be single words rather longest possible substrings. Order among words also needs to be maintained. That's why

> awesome is Seattle

in the sentence above gives us

> awesome, is and Seattle

I am not sure if something like this can be done with a regex though, since it is greedy. Would appreciate any insight into this!
I'm familiar with both C# and Java and could use either of their regex libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to express such a pattern directly with a regex.

You'll need to list all allowed combinations:

```
Seattle is awesome|Seattle is|Seattle|is awesome|is|awesome
```

or more succinctly:

```
Seattle( is( awesome)?)?|is( awesome)?|awesome
```

You can programmatically transform your input string to this format.

Comment: This quickly becomes cumbersome for any non-trivial input string.

Comment: As I said, you don't have to perform this transformation manually. Note the similarity to a suffix tree. In fact, in case the performance of the regex shouldn't be good enough, you can easily create an algorithm that builds on the suffix tree directly instead of using a regex.

Comment: @dtb - are you thinking of a suffix tree of words, or of characters?  If of words, do you know where there's a good generic<? extends Object> suffix-tree implementation?  Writing your own, or even adapting one for characters, is not what I'd call "easy", speaking from experience.  (Also, see my alternate impl below - it's extremely high-speed - just one == comparison per search-string-to-target-position comparison, plus more for matches.)

Comment: @Ed Staub: a suffix tree of words. Actually, since the tree would contain only one sentence, you wouldn't really need build up the suffix tree but could simply operate on the sentence itself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with a regex.  Wikipedia has a good article on the [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Comment: I knew about it but for matching characters.i need to match words here, although i could modify the algo. A Regex gives me the flexibility to add more delimiters between words (instead of just spaces).

Comment: This is not the longest common subsequence problem: it's the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: Also, it's possible to find common substrings within a string using [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) in a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your problem a little further? It sounds a lot more like a search engine than simple string matching. I would highly recommend checking out Apache Lucene -- it has a bit of a learning curve, but it is a great little tool for smart searching. It handles lots of things that are gotchas when dealing with search. You can set up the scoring of hits to do pretty much exactly what you describe.

Comment: Generally, posts like this "answer" should be left as comments. Asking questions of the OP, and making *generalized* recommendations (without addressing question specifics), you're adding *commentary*.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, *not tested*.  This returns an iterator on lists of strings.  Each list is a matching subsequence.
Just put spaces between the members of the list to print.  If this is getting used *a lot*, the use of intern() may be bad.

```
static Iterator<List<String>> getSequences(String squery, String starget)
{
    List<String> query = Arrays.asList(squery.split(" "));
    for ( int i = 0; i < query.size(); i++)
        query.set(i, query.get(i).intern());
    List<String> target = Arrays.asList(starget.split(" "));;
    for ( int i = 0; i < target.size(); i++)
        target.set(i, target.get(i).intern());

    // Because the strings are all intern'ed, this HashSet acts like we want -
    // If two lists are the same sequence of words, they are equal.
    // It's used to remove duplicates.
    HashSet<List<String>> ret = new HashSet<List<String>>();
    for ( int qBegin = 0; qBegin < query.size(); qBegin++ )     {
        for ( int tBegin = 0; tBegin < target.size(); tBegin++ ) {
            for ( int iCursor = 0; 
                  iCursor < min(query.size()-qBegin, target.size()- tBegin); 
                  iCursor++)                {
                if ( query.get(qBegin+iCursor)==target.get(tBegin+iCursor) )
                    ret.add(query.subList(qBegin, qBegin+iCursor+1));
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret.iterator();
}

static int min(int a, int b) { return (a<b)? a:b; }
```

Comment: This isn't right for a couple of reasons:  
- It doesn't return substring matches that don't start at the head of the query string  
- It doesn't prune for longest substring.  
I'm leaving it because the intern'ing hack should probably be used in any good solution - possibly using a [Guava interner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) instead.